# confused in the structure of a negative sentence

Tags: word-order, negation, participles

I make a negative sentence like this:

> They are **not trying** to make me confuse.
>   **or**
>   They are **trying not** to make me confuse.

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 3):

First, your usage of `confuse` as an intransitive verb is wrong. You can instead do one of:

> ... to make me **confused**
>
> ... to make me **confuse something**
>
> ... to **confuse me**

As for the negation, changing the word order changes which part you're negating:

> They are **not trying** to make me confused.
>
> They are trying **not** to **make** me confused.

The implication is that (assuming the context is that *they are explaining something*)

- First example: they don't have the intention to confuse me, but perhaps unintentionally are doing so.
- Second: they are actively trying to explain with as much clarity and as little confusion as possible